# Add Tab Bar Controller to Page View Controller swift app

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

Working with IOS8 and Swift,I'm developing an app that consists in:

```
 - Page View Controller as Initial View Controller
 - Navigation Controller1 -> First View Controller
 - Navigation Controller2 -> Second View Controller
 - Navigation Controller3 -> Third View Controller
```

And I'm trying to add a tab bar into the app, adding an embedded Tab Bar Controller into each Navigation Controller, but when the app starts the view controllers are black without the content. Anyone can suggest me how can I do it?

Comment: According to Apple's guidelines, a tab bar controller should not be embedded in a navigation controller.

Comment: and then which is the way that the tab bar controller and page view controller can coexist together and are synchronized in the same app? Sorry for my inexperience

Comment: I have the same issue. My pageviewcontroller is working . After the user swipes on all the initial pageviewcontroller screens I want him to land on my tabbarcontroller..How can I achieve this? Pls let me know if you have figured this